# PHP 'list' working on non-numerical arrays?

Tags: php, list, construct

```
  $colors = array(
    'r' => 'a',
    'g' => 'b',
    'b' => 'c'
);

list($v, $k) = each($colors);

echo $v . " " . $k
```

Now the above prints r a
which I'm surprise since I thought the 'list' construct only works for numerical array. Why does it work?

Comment: Because it works for all arrays.

Comment: @Felix Kling its in the documentation `list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.`

Comment: @Baba what is this [list](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Comment: @jhonraymos it a very useful function to extract array values ... works like extract but you can specify variable name with list ... the  examples in the PHP doc would help http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you are right [list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical indices start at 0.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) but he reason why your code is working its because of `each`.

`each` `traverse an array` therefore converted the `keys` to `numerical` example if you run the following :

```
$foo = array("r"=>"a");
$bar = each($foo);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($bar);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [value] => a
    [0] => r
    [key] => r
)
```

You can use that  `array('r' => 'a');` has been converted to `array(0 => 'r', 1 => 'a');` therefore you can now use `list` since they now have `numerical keys`

[FROM PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php)

> each Return the current key and value pair from an array and advance the array cursor.
>
> each Returns the current key and value pair from the array array. This pair is returned in a four-element array, with the keys 0, 1, key, and value. Elements 0 and key contain the key name of the array element, and 1 and value contain the data.

Also

> each() is typically used in conjunction with list() to traverse an array, here's an example:

Comment: Actually, you didn't explain it :)

Answer (score 2):

Read the manual closer for [`each()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php):

> Returns the current key and value pair from the array array. This pair is returned in a four-element array, with the keys 0, 1, key, and value. Elements 0 and key contain the key name of the array element, and 1 and value contain the data.

So when you do `each($colors)`, the following is returned:

```
array(0 => 'r' => 1 => 'a', 'key' => 'r', 'value' => 'a')
```

Then `list()` takes the values for `0` and `1` and assigns them to `$v` and `$k` respectively. Make sense?